# Chua's circuit using python and graphing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, graphics

I tried to implement the Chua system using Python. But the graph is very different from what we need. Implementation with such a system

[image]

I haven’t found anywhere on the Internet and tried to do it myself. But in python I still have little experience.

What I get:
[image: what I receive]

What I need:
[image: what I need]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

a,b,e,x2=2.8,3,0.03,9
def f(y, t):
 y1, y2, y3 = y
 return [(-a/b)*(y2-y1),
 (-1/b)*((y2-y1)+y3)+(e/b)*(x2-y2),
         (b*y2)]

t = np.linspace(0,20,2001)
y0 = [1, -1, 10]
[y1,y2,y3]=odeint(f, y0, t, full_output=False).T
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white') 
ax=Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot(y1,y2,y3,linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel('y1')
plt.ylabel('y2')
plt.title("primary: y0 = [1, -1, 10]")
y0 = [1.0001, -1, 10]
[y1,y2,y3]=odeint(f, y0, t, full_output=False).T
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white') 
ax=Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot(y1,y2,y3,linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel('y1')
plt.ylabel('y2')
plt.title("primary: y0 = [1.0001, -1, 10]")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know particularly well Chua's oscillator and unless I'm mistaken, I did suppose there is just an error in your ODE system definition.

Simply based on wikipedia english page of [Chua's circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua%27s_circuit). It seems that you failed to provide an expression of the function `f` describing the electrical response of the nonlinear resistor. So, starting from the given equations and expression of `f`, here's my try with `odeint`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# parameters
alpha = 15.395
beta = 28
R = -1.143
C_2 = -0.714

def chua(u, t):
    x, y, z = u  
    # electrical response of the nonlinear resistor
    f_x = C_2*x + 0.5*(R-C_2)*(abs(x+1)-abs(x-1))
    dudt = [alpha*(y-x-f_x), x - y + z, -beta * y]
    return dudt

# time discretization
t_0 = 0
dt = 1e-3
t_final = 300
t = np.arange(t_0, t_final, dt)

# initial conditions
u0 = [0.1,0,0]
# integrate ode system
sol = odeint(chua, u0, t)

# 3d-plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

ax.plot(sol[:,0],sol[:,1],sol[:,2])
```

which gives the intended chaotic behavior in 3d:

[image: chaotic_chua]

and this nice time evolution in x-y plane:

[image: chua_gif]

Hope this helps solving your problem with your own set of parameters.